# Why Krylov subspaces for nonsymmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Why do we use a Krylov subspace as a search space? I saw an answer here [What makes Krylov subspaces so special?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704957/what-makes-krylov-subspaces-so-special/2714985#2714985). But this answer uses the assumption that $A$ is symmetric. I want to motivate using Krylov methods for non-symmetric matrices (GCR, ORTHOMIN), how do I motivate using Krylov subspace as a search space?

The only argument I could come up with was that the solution $x^{\star}$ is in $K_j$, where $j$ is the degree of a minimal polynomial of $A$, but I think this argument lacks value, beacuse most of the times we make fewer operations than $j$ to approximate the solution.